# Is there an IDE for Blackberry phones?

Tags: blackberry

Is there an IDE for Blackberry phones? I want one that can be installed like an app and run on your phone, just like an IDE on your personal computer. An app that codes in Python specifically, JavaScript and the C languages would be great. Does it exist or am I dreaming?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want an IDE on your "phone" - possibly a tablet device, but umm... You can get different interpreted languages on Android using ASE but no - how would you even design the GUI, the code etc...? So sadly, it's a dream for now (if even technically possibly, it's impractical due to UI). Might as well just VPN to a server and use the screen to develop on the server with all the libraries and tools required.

**update**: seen edit of OP, so although it remains possible, my answer is *you're dreaming*

Answer (score 0):

Actually, codepen.io has a good interfaces for coding HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
Using a 5.5 inches phone looks nice for me.